# substracting value from value above automatically - no loop

Tags: r

I am trying to get a balance value from a df that looks like this

```
df1
Name   Year    Ch1    Origin
A      1995    x1      a
A      1996    x2      b
A      1997    x3      a
A      2000    x4      a
B      1997    y1      c
B      1998    y2      c
.....
```

while Ch1 is numerical.
and I want to add an extra col to have this value:

```
Name   Year   Ch1    Bil
A      1995    x1    
A      1996    x2    %of year before (x2-x1/x1*100)%
A      1997    x3    %of year before (x3-x2/x2*100)%
A      2000    x4    %of year before (x4-x3/x3*100)%
B      1997    y1  
B      1998    y2    %of year before (y2-y1/x1*100)%
.....
```

now I know I could create a loop looking something like this:

```r
for (i in nrow(df1))
  if (df[i,1]==df[i-1,1]) {
    df$Bil<-(df[i,3]-df[i-1,3])/df[i-1,3]*100
  } else ...
```

Is there a more elegant or quicker way to calculate this? This way I really need to make sure that the dataset is in the right order (going from older to recent years). Lets say also dependant on an extra detail such as origin so that the calculation only happens if name and origin are the same?

Thank you!

Comment: The math isn't clear to me, what are the actual numbers you expect in our `Bil` column? Is `Origin` important for anything? Is grouping by `Name`?

Comment: grouping by `name` and `Origin`

Comment: I want to see how the number differs from the number given the year before, percentage vise

Comment: so I think I actually didn't describe it right I would rather calulate 
`(x2-x1)/x1*100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three solutions require the data be in the correct order within each `Name`. For instance, you can interleave names of "A" and "B" (all groupings below will handle it), but the years should likely be non-decreasing.

Prepping by putting in real `Ch1`:

```r
set.seed(42)
df1$Ch1 <- c(sort(sample(20, size=4)), sort(sample(20, size=2)))
```

#### Base R

```r
df1 <- df1[order(df1$Name, df1$Year),]
df1$Bil <- ave(df1$Ch1, df1$Name, df1$Origin,
               FUN=function(z) 100 * c(0, diff(z) / head(z, n = -1)))
df1
#   Name Year Ch1 Origin        Bil
# 1    A 1995   6      a   0.000000
# 2    A 1996  15      b   0.000000
# 3    A 1997  18      a 200.000000
# 4    A 2000  19      a   5.555556
# 5    B 1997  10      c   0.000000
# 6    B 1998  13      c  30.000000
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  arrange(Name, Year) %>%
  group_by(Name, Origin) %>%
  mutate(
    Bil = 100 * c(0, diff(Ch1) / head(Ch1, n = -1))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
df1DT <- as.data.table(df1)
setorder(df1DT, Name, Year)
df1DT[, Bil := 100 * c(0, diff(Ch1) / head(Ch1, n = -1)), by = .(Name, Origin)]
```

Comment: Thank you! If I want to group it by Name and Origin do I just add this to `group_by(Name+Origin) %>%`
as for the calculation I tried to make it a little clearer above, unsure how to adjust the formular in your solution tho! Thank you

Comment: dplyr: `group_by(Name, origin)`. datatable: `by=.(Name,Origin)`. Base R: `ave(df1$Year, df1$Name, df1$Origin, ...)` or `ave(df1$Year, df1[,c("Name","Origin")], ...)`.

Comment: Oh, I see your variables `x1` et al ... that was stupid of me ...

Comment: Thanks! 
how can I make sure again that before its in order per name and year?

Comment: `order` (base, datatable) or `arrange` (dplyr) are your friends, but you only need to order by year ... if you want to group by name, that's fine and aesthetic, but has no impact on the grouped calculations.

Comment: antonina, does that answer your questions?

Comment: is there a way that I can include a condition? 
IF Ch1>Ch2 then -Ch1/Ch2
IF Ch1<Ch2 then Ch2/Ch1

Comment: If `Ch2` is just another column next to `Ch1`, then you can use base `ifelse`, `dplyr::if_else`, or `data.table::fifelse`, as in `if_else(Ch1 > Ch2, -Ch1/Ch2, Ch2/Ch1)` (on a vector).

Comment: sorry, i tried to write it in an understandable way the 1st value of Ch1 vs the 2nd value of Ch1, so e.g. x1, x2.

Comment: `if_else(Ch1[-n()] > Ch1[-1], -Ch1[-n()]/Ch1[-1], Ch1[-1]/Ch1[-n()])`? But this will not produce the right number of rows (it will be `n-1` rows), so you need to figure out which end needs some default value (or `NA`). This might be branching into a new question.

Comment: In base or `data.table`, `Ch1[-n()]` is `head(Ch1,n=-1)`. You can use `Ch1[-1]` in all three.